# Elasticsearch Java API: Create amd reuse node

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

Hi,

maybe I'm missing some understanding about the internals of elasticsearch. What I want to do is to create an embedded ES node, but keep the indices persistent across multiple startups of my application.

This is my startup code (executed on each application startup):

```java
Node node = nodeBuilder().build().start();
```

Then I do some indexing/querying and at some time, the application will stop. Now if I restart the application, all of my data is lost and a new empty node will be created on the fileystem.

Is it possible to reuse a previously created node together with its data using the Java API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution to my problem: The name of the node can be set in the settings. If you do so, the node and its data will be reused on restart.

```
ImmutableSettings.Builder settings
            = ImmutableSettings.builder();
settings.put("node.name", "nameOfTheNode"); // set the name to reuse the node
settings.put("path.data", "/opt/elasticsearch/data"); // the data will be stored in this folder

Node node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder()
        .settings(settings)
        .clusterName("nameOfTheCluser")
        .data(true) // make the node store data
        .node()
        .start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation creates a "transparent" node until the program is shut down.

To make things independent, you have to download the elastic search server from [here](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch). It will actually keep the nodes in the harddisk and provide an api for you to access them.

With that said, you have to connect your java application with your server using [TransportClient()](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html).
All the information will be kept to the elastic search server and therefore will be accessible by many clients. You can even [query your server with curl](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_index_and_query_a_document.html).

Comment: Ok, so there's no possibility to manage the server by myself? That would be nice, since I only need elasticsearch for this one application. Controling it by code would make deployment much simpler. I'm wondering why my implementation keeps the state in the filesystem anyway...